# Merging multiple pandas datasets with non-unique index

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have several similarly structured pandas dataframes stored in a dictionary. I access a dataframe in the following way.

```
ex_dict[df1]
date        df1price1   df1price2
10-20-2015     100         150
10-21-2015      90         100
```

I want to merge all of these dataframes into one dataframe by date. The dates are overlapping, but not all dataframes include all dates.

I need to go from this

```
df1
date        df1price1   df1price2
10-20-2015     100         150
10-21-2015      90         100
10-22-2015     100         140

df2
date        df2price1   df2price2
10-20-2015     110         140
10-21-2015      90         110
10-23-2015     110         120

df3
date        df3price1   df3price2
10-20-2015     100         150
10-22-2015      90         100
10-23-2015      80         130
```

to this:

```
df_all
date        df1price1   df1price2 ... df3price1   df3price2
10-20-2015     100         150    ...    100         150
10-21-2015      90         100    ...    NaN         NaN
10-22-2015     100         140    ...     90         100
10-23-2015     NaN         NaN    ...     80         130
```

I've tried lots of things, but I can't get it to work, short of repeatedly merging 2 at a time to create a new dataframe and then remerging onto that. The number of dataframes I need to merge varies between 4 and 10, so I need a way to do this automatically (hence why I thought a passing a dict might work).

Any help on this would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `pandas.concat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `concat` followed by a `groupby('date')` to flatten the result.

```
In [22]: pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).groupby('date').max()
Out[22]:
            df1price1  df1price2  df2price1  df2price2  df3price1  df3price2
date
10-20-2015        100        150        110        140        100        150
10-21-2015         90        100         90        110        NaN        NaN
10-22-2015        100        140        NaN        NaN         90        100
10-23-2015        NaN        NaN        110        120         80        130
```

**Edit:** As BrenBarn points out in the comments, you can use `concat(axis=1)` if you set the join column as the index of your dataframes:

```
df1.index = df1.date
df2.index = df2.date
df3.index = df3.date

In [44]: pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
Out[44]:
                  date  df1price1  df1price2        date  df2price1  \
10-20-2015  10-20-2015        100        150  10-20-2015        110
10-21-2015  10-21-2015         90        100  10-21-2015         90
10-22-2015  10-22-2015        100        140         NaN        NaN
10-23-2015         NaN        NaN        NaN  10-23-2015        110

            df2price2        date  df3price1  df3price2
10-20-2015        140  10-20-2015        100        150
10-21-2015        110         NaN        NaN        NaN
10-22-2015        NaN  10-22-2015         90        100
10-23-2015        120  10-23-2015         80        130
```

Comment: You can just use `concat` with `axis=1`.

Comment: @BrenBarn no that won't match up the dates

Comment: It should whenever they're the same.

Comment: You also should drop `date` column in each dataframe to achieve desired output

Comment: The groupby did it. Before I had gotten to the second solution, but I couldn't flatten it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple merge on `date` column:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='date', how='outer').merge(df3, on='date', how='outer').set_index('date')

In [107]: df1.merge(df2, on='date', how='outer').merge(df3, on='date', how='outer').set_index('date')
Out[107]:
            df1price1  df1price2  df2price1  df2price2  df3price1  df3price2
date
10-20-2015        100        150        110        140        100        150
10-21-2015         90        100         90        110        NaN        NaN
10-22-2015        100        140        NaN        NaN         90        100
10-23-2015        NaN        NaN        110        120         80        130
```

Some explanation: First you merging `df1` and `df2` on column `date` with joining `outer`. The the resulted dataframe you merging with `df3` with the same attributes. And finnaly setting index `date` for your resulted dateframe. If your dataframes have `date` columns as index you could first do `reset_index` for each of them and merge on the column name containing `date`

Comment: I think that the reset_index would not work because the dates are not necessarily unique in each dataset. I kept getting an error on that one.