# Pandas time series comparison with missing data/records

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

This question is somewhat related to an earlier question from me ([Remapping `numpy.array` with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658811/remapping-numpy-array-with-missing-values)), where I was struggling with time series with missing data, and someone suggested *"use Pandas!"*. So here I go...

I'm dealing with large data sets, basically consisting of time series from different observation sites, where I would like to statistically compare the sites. These data sets are quite messy; lots of missing data (indicated with e.g. `-99`), missing time records (one station might have the time record, another not), and I only want to include/compare data where either (1) all sites have data for a certain variable, or (2) the two sites I would like to compare have data for that variable, ignoring whether the other sites (don't) have data.

Take this minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""\
  1,  2001-01-01, 00:00, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0
  1,  2001-01-01, 01:00, 1.1, 0.6, 2.0
  1,  2001-01-01, 02:00, 1.2, 0.7, 3.0
  1,  2001-01-01, 03:00, 1.3, 0.8, 4.0

  2,  2001-01-01, 00:00, 2.0, -99, -99
  2,  2001-01-01, 01:00, -99, 1.6, 2.0
  2,  2001-01-01, 02:00, 2.2, 1.7, 3.0
  2,  2001-01-01, 03:00, 2.3, 1.8, 4.0

  3,  2001-01-01, 00:00, 3.0, 2.5, 1.0
  3,  2001-01-01, 01:00, 3.1, 2.6, -99
  3,  2001-01-01, 02:00, -99, -99, 3.0
  3,  2001-01-01, 03:00, 3.3, 2.8, 4.0
  3,  2001-01-01, 04:00, 3.4, 2.9, 5.0
""")

columns = ['id','date','time','T','Td','cc']
df = pd.read_table(data, header=None, names=columns, delimiter=',', na_values=-99, parse_dates=[['date','time']])
```

Where `-99` indicates a missing value. I would like to compare the data (columns `T`,`Td`,`cc`) from different sites (column `id`), but as mentioned, only if either two or all `id`'s have data for the variable I'm interested in (completely ignoring whether the data in other columns is missing).

So for this example, if all sites need to have data, comparing `T` would only result in comparing data from `2001-01-01, 00:00` and `03:00`, since for the other times, either `id=2` or `id=3` is missing `T`, and the last time record for `id=3` is completely absent in the other `id`'s.

I've been playing with this for hours now, but honestly I don't really know where to start. Is it possible to extract a `numpy.array`, using the criteria outlined above, of size `n_sites x n_valid_values` (`3x2`, for this example), which I could then use for further analysis?

*EDIT* As a partial, but really (*really*) ugly solution, something like this seems to work:

```
# Loop over all indexes where T is nan:
for i in np.where(df['T'].isnull())[0]:
    # For each of them, set records with the same date_time to nan
    j = np.where(df['date_time'] == df['date_time'][i])[0]
    df['T'][j] = np.nan
# Drop all records where T is nan
df2 = df.dropna(subset=['T'])

# Group by the different stations:
g = df2.groupby('id')

# Get the arrays (could automate this based on the unique id's):
v1 = g.get_group(1)['T']
v2 = g.get_group(2)['T']
v3 = g.get_group(3)['T']
```

But this still doesn't drop the record for `id=3`, `date_time=2001-01-01, 04:00`, and I guess/hope that there are more elegant methods with `Pandas`.

Comment: why these `2,  2001-01-01, 00:00, 2.0, -99, -99` -99 are ok?

Comment: In this case I'm only interested in whether the `T` column has data, ignoring the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method (based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34985243/3581217 answer) which seems to work is to create a `Dataframe` where the observations from the different sites have different columns, then a `dropna()` with `subset` set to either all columns, or the two sites I want to compare, which drops all rows where data is missing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data1 = StringIO("""\
  1,  2001-01-01, 00:00, 1.0
  1,  2001-01-01, 01:00, 1.1
  1,  2001-01-01, 02:00, 1.2
  1,  2001-01-01, 03:00, 1.3
""")

data2 = StringIO("""\
  2,  2001-01-01, 00:00, 2.0
  2,  2001-01-01, 01:00, -99
  2,  2001-01-01, 02:00, 2.2
  2,  2001-01-01, 03:00, 2.3
""")

data3 = StringIO("""\
  3,  2001-01-01, 00:00, 3.0
  3,  2001-01-01, 01:00, 3.1
  3,  2001-01-01, 02:00, -99
  3,  2001-01-01, 03:00, 3.3
  3,  2001-01-01, 04:00, 3.4
""")

columns = ['id','date','time','T1']
df1 = pd.read_table(data1, header=None, names=columns, delimiter=',', na_values=-99, parse_dates=[['date','time']])
columns = ['id','date','time','T2']
df2 = pd.read_table(data2, header=None, names=columns, delimiter=',', na_values=-99, parse_dates=[['date','time']])
columns = ['id','date','time','T3']
df3 = pd.read_table(data3, header=None, names=columns, delimiter=',', na_values=-99, parse_dates=[['date','time']])

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).groupby('date_time').max()
df = df.dropna(subset=['T1','T2','T3'])
```

The resulting `Dataframe` looks like:

```
In [232]: df
Out[232]: 
                      T1   T2   T3  id
date_time                             
2001-01-01 00:00:00  1.0  2.0  3.0   3
2001-01-01 03:00:00  1.3  2.3  3.3   3
```

And if I want to compare only two sites, ignoring in this case `T3`, a `df.dropna(subset=['T1','T2'])` results in:

```
In [234]: df
Out[234]: 
                      T1   T2   T3  id
date_time                             
2001-01-01 00:00:00  1.0  2.0  3.0   3
2001-01-01 02:00:00  1.2  2.2  NaN   3
2001-01-01 03:00:00  1.3  2.3  3.3   3
```

Is this the way to go? Still feels a bit non-Panda-ish..?